# How do I run a php file inside a phar?

Tags: php, phar

I put in the phar archive the php-file 'test.php' with the code:

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

How to start the file and display hello on the screen? With state files, for example txt such works, but with PHP there is no:

```
echo file_get_contents('phar://archive.phar/test.php');
```

Comment: Have you read https://www.sitepoint.com/packaging-your-apps-with-phar/ ?

Comment: You use `require`, not `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this
require_once('phar://archive.phar/test.php');